What prompted Jeff to mention Miles' commitment to school?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Miles, evading the Prowler, enters his home via a window. Jeff, hearing the noise, confronts him but is surprised to find Miles instead
of an intruder. As Miles hugs Jeff for comfort, Ron Morales enters, wondering if an earthquake caused the commotion:

Miles: Can I sleep here tonight?
Jeff: Miles. It's a weeknight. You made a commitment to that
school.
Rio Morales: Jeff. He's upset.

I felt that Jeff’s reminders to Miles about his school responsibilities seemed
forced, as Miles would rather sleep over at their place than focus on school.
What prompted Jeff to mention Miles' commitment to school?

Miles has committed to sleeping at his boarding school, not coming home each night

By being at home on a school night, Miles is implicitly ditching homework, and risking being tired due to lack of sleep the next day. And the school is a big deal for Miles and his family.
Miles lives at the Brooklyn Visions Academy - he has a dorm room, where his books and homework are; by being at his parents' apartment and not at school, Miles is missing study/homework time, and since he will have to travel back to the school in the morning, he'll miss sleep as well, diminishing his ability to perform well during that school day.
Jefferson is already worried about Miles' commitment to the school - in an early scene, when Miles is talking about quitting, Jefferson says:

No way. You passed the entry test just like everybody else, ok! You have an opportunity here, you wanna blow that, huh? You want to end up like your Uncle?

so it's in-character for Jefferson to immediately jump to concerns that Miles is not taking the school seriously enough.

As a side note to this, recidivism to home from college is really bad in early years and can often lead to dropping out (I remember several people from my freshman year who went home every weekend and never came back after the first year), so it's common for parents to be advised to not let their kids come home too often, but rather adjust to the new situation. Similarly, Miles has this golden opportunity for the new school, and his parents don't want him to become homesick and spend too much time away from school.
